# why stop isRoundNumber with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following code in Java:

```
public static boolean isRoundNumber(String s) {
    System.out.println("the string is: "+s);
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("check 1");
        return false;
    }
    if (s.length() == 1) {
        System.out.println("check 2");
        return Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0));
    } else {
        System.out.print("checking: " + s.charAt(0)+ " | ");
        return (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0))
                && isRoundNumber(s.substring(1)));
    }
}
```

When I type

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("the string is a round number: " + isRoundNumber("1x143"));
}
```

The output is

```
the string is: 1x143
checking: 1 | the string is: x143
checking: x | the string is a round number: false
```

When I remove `Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) &&` from the `else` case, the output is

```
the string is: 1x143
checking: 1 | the string is: x143
checking: x | the string is: 143
checking: 1 | the string is: 43
checking: 4 | the string is: 3
check 2
the string is a round number: true
```

Why will the method stop (and give the correct answer) if I do not remove `Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0))` in the return?

Comment: becuase 'x' is not a digit?

Comment: You can't remove it because the method should return true.

Comment: Is this a homework problem where you have to use recursion?  If not, this is not a great strategy for determining if a string consists only of digits...  You could use a regular expression instead `[0-9]+`

Comment: @ sharonbn  I know :-) That is not my question.

Comment: @BaileyS: it is homework (master study computer science - data structures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why will the method stop (and give the correct answer) if I do not remove `Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0))` in the return?

It stops because the `&&` operator *short-circuits* the expression:

```
return (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0))
                && isRoundNumber(s.substring(1)));
```

With `&&`, if the first operand (the bit before the `&&`) is `false`, the second operand is never evaluated — and so the recursive call to `isRoundNumber` doesn't happen. The second operand (the bit after the `&&`) is only evaluated if the first operand is `true`.

Comment: I am sorry, I changed my question. It must be "if I do not remove"

Comment: here's no need to check the rest of the string: Why??

Comment: @user1554530: I've updated the answer based on the updated question.

Comment: @JB I red your link and accepted the answers. Thank you for your tip. edit: Ok, I understand now. I can only accept one answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe for the OP it is good to explain that you can 'disable' short circuiting by using a single operator(&, | instead of a double one && and ||, this will evaluate every expression within a statement).

Answer (score 0):

> Why will the method stop (and give the correct answer) if I do not remove Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) in the return?

Because `&&`is a short-circuit operator. When Java evaluates the value of `a && b`, it starts by evaluating `a`. If it's false, it doesn't even evaluate `b` because, whatever the value of `b` is, the result will always be false. That's why it doesn't call `isRoundNumber(s.substring(1))`: `Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0))` is false because the first character is 'x'.

Note that the same is true for `||`: `a || b` doesn't even evaluate `b` if `a` is true., because whatever the value of b is, the expression will be true.

Comment: That's true *becuase 'x' is not a digit*.

Comment: What is true? Why the downvote? `Character.isDigit('x')` is false.

Comment: There is not a short circuit logic operator present in the code.

Comment: I'm not down-voted but I think it gives an invalid return.

Comment: @BaileyS yes, there is. The OP kepts changing his code again and again and messed up. TJ fixed it.

Comment: Thank you all! I learned something today about Short-circuit evaluation